# Existence of $x_0 \in (0,1)$, s.t. $f'(x_0)+1/x_0 f(x_0)=2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, rolles-theorem

> $f(x)$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$, $\int_{0}^{1}{f(x)}dx=1/2$, how to imply exist $x_0 \in (0,1)$, s.t. $f'(x_0)+1/x_0 f(x_0)=2$

I think it is equal to prove $\exists x_0, s.t. (x_0f(x_0))'=2x_0$
I tried to use $F(x)=xf(x)-x^2$ and use the Rolle theorem but failed.
Then I tried $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}{f(y)}dy$ and use the Taylor theorem but also failed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rolles theorem helps!

consider $$h(x)=\int_0^x f(x)dx-x^2/2$$ note that $h(0)=h(1)=0\rightarrow h'(c)=0$ for some $c\in(0,1)$ now $$h'(c)=0\implies f(c)-c=0$$ also let $$g(x)=xf(x)-x^2$$ $g(0)=g(c)=0\rightarrow g'(x_0)=0$ where $x_0\in(0,c) $ $$g'(x_0)=0\implies x_0f'(x_0)+f(x_0)-2x_0=0$$ $$\implies f'(x_0)+1/x_0 f(x_0)=2$$ hence proved

Comment: Got it, thank you! I used the Rolles theorem and got the second part, but failed to get a point $x=c$ $ s.t.  f(c)=c$

Comment: @bill yes that part was tricky indeed!